# iOS (Xcode 6.2) Paypal (2.11.0) integration - 64 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, xcode, paypal, arm64

I have integrated Paypal 2.11.0 in my iOS App (for iOS 7 and 8). Paypal is working fine but when I try to distribute my App (On Archive) it is showing linker error "64 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64".

How to fix it.

Valid Architecture is armv7,armv7s,arm64

> duplicate symbol l034 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalPaymentViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentMethodCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l035 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalPaymentViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentMethodCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l036 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentMethodCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l037 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentMethodCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l026 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPDeviceCheckViewController.o)
>   duplicate symbol l027 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPDeviceCheckViewController.o)
>   duplicate symbol l028 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPDeviceCheckViewController.o)
>   duplicate symbol l033 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentMethodCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>   duplicate symbol l034 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalPaymentViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>   duplicate symbol l035 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalPaymentViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>   duplicate symbol l036 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>   duplicate symbol l037 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>   duplicate symbol l038 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentMethodCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>   duplicate symbol l034 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalPaymentViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPServiceRequest.o)
>   duplicate symbol l026 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPSelectPayMethodViewControllerIOS6.o)
>   duplicate symbol l027 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPSelectPayMethodViewControllerIOS6.o)
>   duplicate symbol l028 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPSelectPayMethodViewControllerIOS6.o)
>   duplicate symbol l029 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPSelectPayMethodViewControllerIOS6.o)
>   duplicate symbol l030 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPSelectPayMethodViewControllerIOS6.o)
>   duplicate symbol l031 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPSelectPayMethodViewControllerIOS6.o)
>   duplicate symbol l023 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPBaseViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalProfileSharingViewController.o)
>   duplicate symbol l016 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentAttributeSelectionCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l017 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentAttributeSelectionCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l005 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPTableViewCellDefaults.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l007 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAHeaderTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l008 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAHeaderTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l009 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAHeaderTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l010 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPCreditCardMethodCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l011 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPCreditCardMethodCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l012 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAHeaderTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l013 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAHeaderTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l014 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l015 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l016 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentAttributeSelectionCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l017 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentAttributeSelectionCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l018 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l019 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l020 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAnalyticsTracker.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(UIImage+ImageEffects.o)
>   duplicate symbol l099 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAuthConsentViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraAnalyticsTracker.o)
>   duplicate symbol l016 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentAttributeSelectionCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASecurityCodeTableViewCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l017 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentAttributeSelectionCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASecurityCodeTableViewCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l018 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASecurityCodeTableViewCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l019 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASecurityCodeTableViewCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l020 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAnalyticsTracker.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASecurityCodeTableViewCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l018 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPSelectPayMethodViewControllerIOS7.o)
>   duplicate symbol l019 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPSelectPayMethodViewControllerIOS7.o)
>   duplicate symbol l020 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPAnalyticsTracker.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPSelectPayMethodViewControllerIOS7.o)
>   duplicate symbol l010 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPCreditCardMethodCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAHeaderTableViewCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l011 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPCreditCardMethodCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAHeaderTableViewCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l022 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalProfileSharingViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalFuturePaymentViewController.o)
>   duplicate symbol l035 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PayPalPaymentViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(FPTIData.o)
>   duplicate symbol l036 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAViewController.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(FPTIData.o)
>   duplicate symbol l033 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentMethodCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPMultipleFieldTableViewCell.o)
>   duplicate symbol l003 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPTableViewCellDefaults.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPViewShake.o)
>   duplicate symbol l004 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPTableViewCellDefaults.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPViewShake.o)
>   duplicate symbol l005 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPTableViewCellDefaults.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPViewShake.o)
>   duplicate symbol l030 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPZebraUI.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPHTML.o)
>   duplicate symbol l013 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FAHeaderTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPModalActivityIndicator.o)
>   duplicate symbol l014 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPModalActivityIndicator.o)
>   duplicate symbol l015 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPModalActivityIndicator.o)
>   duplicate symbol l016 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentAttributeSelectionCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPModalActivityIndicator.o)
>   duplicate symbol l017 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPPaymentAttributeSelectionCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPModalActivityIndicator.o)
>   duplicate symbol l018 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPModalActivityIndicator.o)
>   duplicate symbol l019 in:
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PP2FASMSTableViewCell.o)
>       /Users/rajkumar/Desktop/ThrillCity 2 2/libPayPalMobile.a(PPModalActivityIndicator.o)
>   ld: 64 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably linking your project to the same library or framework more than 1 time. Try to run clean in Xcode on your project, and then rebuild, and also, you should post the symbols and error codes you are receiving.

Comment: I have added the error code, Sorry not able to upload screen shots and I am not adding same library twice I have verified it, cleared derived data , cleaned , restarted and tried everything

Answer (score 0):

It is the problem of PayPal SDK. The library you are using was built with XCode 6.3. And if you are trying to build using lower version than that that is the reason behind the duplications.

In this case:

1. You can update your XCode to version 6.3
2. Try to use PayPal SDK version 2.9.0 for now.

You can see this [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/269).

And for downloading the lower version PayPal SDK see [this](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/releases) link.